# how to detect when another app is using my webservice?

Tags: android, web-services, ios, mobile

I have an ios/android app that uses a proprietary web service that I host.  Is there a way I can detect if another application is using my web services API?  I don't mind sharing the data so much as paying for bandwidth when someone else publishes an app that uses my API.

The only way I can think of accomplishing this is to force the user to sign up for an account and tie their credentials in with the request so I can track who is using the system.  However, I don't want punish the user..

Does anyone have any other alternatives?

Comment: How is it punishing the user? You control the code on both sides, correct? You should be able to work out an in-code key generation / register / auth cycle that's secure enough for your needs and closes the obvious security hole of an ungated service.

Comment: your comment intrigues me.. might I ask you spell it out a bit in the form of an answer?  much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could provide an anonymous version that is performance restricted and allow people to register for a performant version that cost to enable to pay for the bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Along your webservice calls, pass a private key as parameter. In the server side, authenticate this private key and respond only if it is authenticated else return error.
When you want to share the service to a third party, provide them a new key using which they can use your web service.
By this way, you can track how many requests each user is using per day.